# Localization for the Mailing List Module in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: localization, translation, expressionengine, mailing-list

I'm setting a site up with EE2 in a language other than English that has a newsletter. The Mailing List Module seems great for ease of use and the basic functionality we need. We would like to use this if we can get the user interface into the target language.

Is there a way to make the following in another language for this module: 
• message after submitting the sign up form on the site
• confirmation email
• confirmation page on the web site
• the link at the bottom of the email to remove yourself from the list
• confirmation that you have been removed from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do this without going through the .php files:

- First translate the files you need using the [Translation Utility](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/tools/utilities/translation_utility.html). There are several that are used for the Mailing list functionality. Files I know will need to be used for the Mailing List are `core_lang.php` and `mailinglist_lang.php`
- Then move the files you create with that to a folder for the language in the language folder.
- The Translation Utility only translates the things that will be displayed in the messages on the site, not the automated emails. To translate the emails you can use Design>Message Pages>Email Notifications.

Hope this helps someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

The mails are generated inside the file called `email_data.php`. You need to translate that file.

It's located at `/system/expressionengine/language/english/email_data.php`

Comment: Do you know why this file (email_data.php) isn't in list for the Translation Utility? That would be useful.

Comment: Probably due to the HEREDOC used in the file which would make coding the translation utility more complex.